# Regarding JDK version supported for zookeeper 3.5.5

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We are using JDK 11 and are upgrading to JDK 17. The current zookeeper version is 3.5.5. We would like to know the maximum JDK version supported by the current zookeeper version(3.5.5).